# Calling methods on the replacement argument when using .replace()

Tags: javascript, replace

I was playing with `.replace()` recently and found the following behaviour odd. Take the two following code snippets:

```js
const str = "Hello world";
const res = str.replace(/(o)/g, "$1".repeat(3));
console.log(res); // Hellooo wooorld (which I expected)
```

The above print `"Hellooo wooorld"`, which I expected, as I am using `.repeat(3)` on the matched `o` characters.

However, when I apply the same logic and use `.toUpperCase()`, my string remains unchanged:

```js
const str = "Hello world";
const res = str.replace(/(o)/g, "$1".toUpperCase());
console.log(res); // Hello world (expected HellO wOrld)
```

The above, to my surprise, didn't work as it printed the original string and not `"HellO wOrld"`. **So, *why* does the first code snippet work but the second doesn't?**. I am aware that I can use the [replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters) function for this, but I am more concerned about understanding why the first snippet works, and the second doesn't.

Comment: `"$1".toUpperCase()` is still `"$1"`. `"$1".repeat(3)` is `"$1$1$1"`. You pass these strings to the function, not the method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression that the second argument gets evaluated to will replace all occurrences of `$#`-like strings in the passed argument. In the first code, the passed argument is `'$1$1$1'`:

```
const res = str.replace(/(o)/g, "$1".repeat(3));
// interpreter first parses the expression in the second parameter,
// so it knows what to pass to replace:
const res = str.replace(/(o)/g, "$1$1$1");
// THEN the function call occurs
```

In the second code, calling `toUpperCase` on `'$1'` results in the same string, `$1`:

```
const res = str.replace(/(o)/g, "$1".toUpperCase());
// interpreter first parses the expression in the second parameter,
// so it knows what to pass to replace:
const res = str.replace(/(o)/g, "$1");
// THEN the function call occurs
```